# Sending a text message in localhost with PHP

Tags: php, email, text, sms, message

So I'm trying to send a text message to my phone using PHP. I'm able to send a message to my email, but it won't send to my phone. I have exim4 installed if that helps. I'm somewhat of a beginner with this kind of thing, so any help is appreciated. I tried sending the message to ##########@vtext.com

The php code is in mail.php, while the html is in test.html, FYI.

```
<html>
    <form method='post' action='mail.php'>
        To: <input name='to' type='text'><br>
        From: <input name='email' type='text'><br>
        Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
        Message:<br><textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'></textarea><br>
        <input type='submit' value="Send Email"> 
    </form>
</html>

<?php

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    mail($to, $subject,
    $message, "From:" . $email);
?>
```

Comment: don't use this code. if it's on a publicly accessible url, you'll be allowing anyone to use your server for spam.

Comment: This is just on localhost

Comment: You'll need a message provider (smsc) for sending text messages unles you have an email to text provider but you may have to add your php servers ip address to an allow list to allow it to send  it.

Comment: This works for me.  Perhaps your message is too long for text, or is being rejected as spam.

Comment: Why was I able to send the text to my phone from my Gmail?

Comment: What are you putting in the "To:" field @Umbrella? Obviously omitting your number...

Comment: ##@vtext.com  I have code very much like this in one of my projects.

Comment: is it just 10 digits (area code + number)?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the service provider for you phone you have they generally give every phone number a email address. For example 12345678@vtext.com. That will send a text right to your phone for free without any other services. Youll need to make sure your email system is set up correctly as well as ported correctly inside your local host. You can always try a regular email to make sure it works.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/email-to-sms/

You can use any php send mail script and easily send messages.

Other wise youll need a mobile gateway to send texts and those usually charge a fee or if they are free are a pain to deal with from my experience.

Comment: I'm aware of vtext, as I've sent messages to my phone using my Gmail. I've also been successful with sending a message to my email using my code. The only thing that doesn't seem to be working is using this code to send a text to my phone.